# Jetpack Compose: Stack cannot be resolved

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am new to Jetpack compose and I'm currently trying to implement a Stack (composable). For some reason, I can't get a reference to it. I have tried adding it to my imports as shown below, but the *Stack* part is not getting resolved.

```
 import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Stack
```

Autocomplete can't seem to get it either as shown below:

[image: Trying to reference JetPack Compose Stack]

I included `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` among the list of my plugins. Highlighted below is a list of my dependencies:

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta07")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta07")
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.0-beta07")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta07")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.0.0-beta07")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.0.0-beta07")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta07")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:1.0.0-beta07")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.0-beta07")
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Stack is deprecated. Use Box() instead.

Since Version 1.0.0-alpha04: "Stack was renamed to Box. The previously existing Box will be deprecated in favor of the new Box in compose.foundation.layout. The behavior of the new Box is to stack children one on top of another when it has multiple children - this is different from the previous Box, which was behaving similar to a Column. (I94893, b/167680279)"

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui?authuser=1#1.0.0-alpha04

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: So how do I overlay ui elements using Box? I have a box with a verticalPager in it and I want to overlay UI elects over the VertcalPager that do not scroll.  Are there and tutorials or examples of this?